# ADFS understanding possibilities

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, dns, adfs2.0

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. I've read many articles about ADFS setup and what-not, but what I'm failing to understand (since this is not my primary area of work or interest) is if its actually capable of handling what I need handled.

That is: I have a Sharepoint server on domain "domainA". Now, I've been told that using ADFS, I can "delegate" permissions to other external AD's. The way I'm understanding it is, that I can say this other company using "domainB" is allowed to login to my sharepoint server? Is this at all correct? So users of both "domainA" and "domainB" is allowed to login, and I can set sharepoint permissions with users of both AD's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADFS is an instance of a Security Token System (STS).

SP 2010 has its own STS which can be federated with an instance of ADFS in Domain A which allows users to authenticate via the Domain A AD. These users are configured to receive a set of claims from the Domain A AD which SP 2010 uses as permissions (i.e. authorisation).

If you have another domain - Domain B - the normal practice is to install another instance of ADFS on that domain and then federate the two ADFS. These users will also receive a set of claims.

Now users in Domain A authenticate on the Domain A AD and users in Domain B authenticate on the Domain B AD and both have access to the SP2010 application.

To decide where to authenticate, the user will be presented with a Home Realm Discovery screen which will ask them where they want to authenticate. This is out-of-the-box behaviour.

For anything ADFS related, look [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2735.ad-fs-2-0-content-map.aspx).

Comment: You write that one normally has one AD FS instance per domain.  Do you have a reference for this practice?  Thanks.

Comment: Apologies - somewhat misleading. The question was "this other company using "domainB" ". So I assume that the two domains are not within the same company. This is the classic federation scenario. Within the same company, you can get away with one instance but then the two domains need some kind of trust relationship between the two AD.

Comment: Good, cause in my case I need to be able to allow for other companies to get in too. I'm thinking I'm gonna try to setup a new domain controller within my company, but also setup ADFS on it, so as to mimick it being a different company, and test the whole thing like that - thanks for the inputs!